# What does :final name mean in Dart language

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I'm playing with riverpod in flutter, and I got this example

`AsyncError(:final error) => Text('Error: $error'),`

It works, but I'm trying to understand what does `:final error`  mean? If I remove the `:` it throws an error `Object patterns can only use named fields.`

Can you please provide a better example when is required to use it?

Trying to understand a certain syntax in Dart language

Comment: https://dart.dev/language/pattern-types#object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also a feature I wasn't that familiar with but I've been playing around with it. The colon is used to destructure an instance of a class. It's not the `:final` doing anything, it's the complete `:final error`. It must mean that the class `AsyncError` has some field declared as `error` and by writing it like that you can access that variable and make sure it's final when you reference it. The `final` seems to be optional but leaving it out can lead to errors. See this example:

```
void main() {
  test(Foo(value:'test'));
  test(Bar(value:'haha'));
}

test(x) {
  return switch(x) {
    Foo(:final value) => print('this is a Foo with value $value'),
    Bar(:String value) => print('this is a Bar with value ${value = 'asf'}'),
     _ => print('no match')
  };
}

class Foo {
  String value;
  Foo({required this.value});
}

class Bar {
  String value;
  Bar({required this.value});
}
```

This code compiles fine but throws an error at runtime because in the Bar example the assignment to a pattern variable is not allowed. By making it final, you can catch this mistake because then it wouldn't even compile, like for example this:

```
Bar(:final value) => print('this is a Bar with value ${value = 'asf'}'),
```

would be caught already by the IDE as not being possible because value is marked final.

Comment: "This code compiles fine but throws an error at runtime" what error did you get? I have dart 3.4 and no error

Comment: @pskink "bin/dart.dart:10:61: Error: Pattern variables can't be assigned inside the guard of the enclosing guarded pattern.
Try assigning to a different variable.
    Bar(:String value) => print('this is a Bar with value ${value = 'asf'}'),". And using dart 3.3.0

Comment: @pskink same on https://dartpad.dev/ . Try my code block there

Comment: @pskink but I was wrong, that it compiles. It seems to be a compile error, not a runtime error. Although the IDE doesn't complain about it

Comment: @pskink yeah no problem with that. But you're not using the `${value = 'asf'}` that I used

Comment: ohhh i  see it now, sorry for making mess ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Dart recently introduced a feature called pattern matching. I haven't done much with it, but I think this is how it works in your case.

First of all, I think you are relating to this example, right?

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
  final config = ref.watch(fetchConfigurationProvider);

  return switch (config) {
    AsyncError(:final error) => Text('Error: $error'),
    AsyncData(:final value) => Text(value.host),
    _ => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
  };
}
```

`ref.watch(xxx)` seems to return an instance of `AsyncValue`. `AsyncError` and `AsyncData` inherit from `AsyncValue`.

With pattern matching, two things happen in the switch:

1. The type of the instance gets matched. Is the instance of type error, or type data?
2. The property `error` of `AsyncError` gets matched and destructured or the property `value` of `AsyncData` gets matched and destructured.

Both properties can then be used, if matched, as if a variable with their name had been assigned.

The `:` belongs to the matching syntax.

More about patterns in Dart: https://dart.dev/language/patterns

Answer (score 3):

This is the ability to destructure a class instance field. To use the fields of an object at the time of destructuring, you can use the syntax `Object(:[type] field)` (conditionally). Here are more examples:

```dart
AsyncValue? value;
final result = switch (value) {
  AsyncError(:final error) => '$error',
  AsyncError(:var error, :StackTrace stackTrace) => '$error $stackTrace',
  AsyncError(:var error, stackTrace: StackTrace st) => '$error $st',
  AsyncError<int>(:final int value) => '$value',
  AsyncError(:Object error) => '$error',
  AsyncValue<int>(hasValue: true) => 'hasValue is true',
  AsyncValue<int>(:var hasValue) when hasValue == false => '$hasValue',
  _ => 'default',
```

The example itself doesn't make sense here, I only showed the syntax of field extraction. Specify `:` (or just inside the object's parentheses) and use the IDE prompts to see the fields available for destructuring.

Use a custom field when destructuring if necessary (as with `stackTrace: StackTrace st`).

You can also immediately start mapping fields to value, as in the `AsyncValue.hasValue` example. Use the `when` syntax if you need this field later.

There is a very large syntax, I recommend viewing the information using the links below:

- https://dart.dev/language/patterns
- [Records and Pattern Matching in dart - Complete Guide | Sandro Maglione](https://www.sandromaglione.com/articles/records-and-patterns-dart-language#switch-expression-and-destructuring)
- [Dive into Dart's patterns and records](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/dart-patterns-records#0)

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: `(:final error)` is the pattern matching in Dart.
If you remove the colon `:`, Dart no longer recognizes it as pattern matching syntax and instead tries to interpret it as an object pattern.

- The colon `:` indicates the start of the pattern matching syntax.
- `final error` declares a variable error that will hold the error object contained within the AsyncError instance. The `final` keyword is used here to indicate that `error` will not be reassigned.

---

When is required to use it?

> if you want to make your code clean and expressive.

example: Handling a login State

```
abstract class LoginState {}

class Loading extends LoginState {}

class Success extends LoginState {
  final String username;
  Success(this.username);
}

class Error extends LoginState {
  final String message;
  Error(this.message);
}
```

now we can use it as:

```
Widget buildLoginWidget(LoginState state) {
  return state switch {
    Loading => CircularProgressIndicator(),
    Success(:final username) => Text('Welcome, $username!'),
    Error(:final message) => Text('Error: $message'),
  };
}
```

from the example:

> When you I write `Success(:final username) => Text('Welcome, $username!')`, it means Im handling a state by matching the `Success`
> type, extracting the object into a variable named `username`, and then
> using that variable to display a message in my UI with a `Text`
> widget.

Im also just learn this things. Do not hesitate to correct me if im wrong.

Comment: I think the syntax is return switch(state) :)